# CSS box div dropping shadow with gradient

Tags: css

I was wondering how can I drop some shadow in a box like on the apple site:

http://www.apple.com/ipad/

The boxes bellow are dropping a shadow that gets thicker on the laterals, I know how to drop shadow in a uniform way, but how can I produce something similar to those apple boxes on the ipad section?