# Transparency in box shadow

Tags: transparency, css

I am creating a heading for my site. The background of the heading is set as horizontal gradient with background becoming transparent as it goes from left to right.

**WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO**

Can I create box shadow for the heading such that the shadow too becomes transparent as it goes from left to right.

**WHAT I TRIED**

```
width: 500px;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
color: #535353;
left: 45%;
top: 50%;
margin-left: -150px;
margin-top: -200px;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(179,218,221,0.65) 0%, rgba(249,249,249,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(179,218,221,0.65)), color-stop(100%,rgba(249,249,249,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(179,218,221,0.65) 0%,rgba(249,249,249,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(179,218,221,0.65) 0%,rgba(249,249,249,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(179,218,221,0.65) 0%,rgba(249,249,249,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(179,218,221,0.65) 0%,rgba(249,249,249,0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a6b3dadd', endColorstr='#00f9f9f9',GradientType=1 );
border-radius: 5px;

    box-shadow: -5px 0 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: -5px 0 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: -5px 0 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

By using the following I can almost get it, but the transparent gradient dosenot look so good.

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/p7W7M/

Comment: provide a fiddle or html code so we can test

Comment: @SahilPopli: I have added a fiddle. Please do check it

Comment: what you want shadow from left to right it is now right to left

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sahilpopli/p7W7M/2/

Comment: @SahilPopli: Shadow is correct. But can it be made transparent on the right side like a gradient

Comment: how you want i cant understand what you want to do i is transparent in latest fiddle

Comment: @SahilPopli: see the following link http://pe-images.s3.amazonaws.com/type/effects/perspective-shadow/shadow-2-mask.jpg . Here the shodow depth keeps on decreasing. I want somethinng like this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26633/discussion-between-avinash-and-sahil-popli)

Comment: This would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696659/css-box-div-droping-shadow-with-gradient

Answer (score 0):

This can work but not perfectly [jugaad]

```
 box-shadow:60px 5px 0 #ffffff,60px -5px 0 #ffffff,-4px 0px 5px  #000000;
```

[At fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sahilpopli/p7W7M/4/)

Comment: I found a fiddle with my requirement but cannot understand how to implement it in my code. Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/8YsAg/